# Flutter : Why is my builder not getting reloaded after web service call?

Tags: api, web-services, flutter, future

I have written the web service call and is being called in the `initState()` method. A CircularProgressIndicator() is being called if there is no data available. But the progress indicator keeps on rotating even though the web service call is over!

After making a service call, why is my builder not getting reloaded?

I am new to flutter!! Am I going wrong anywhere?

```
    class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
      bool isLoading = false;

      Future<List<OrganizationModel>> fetchOrganizationData() async {
        isLoading = true;
        var response = await http.get(organizationAPI);          
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
          orgModelList = items.map<OrganizationModel>((json) {
            return OrganizationModel.fromJson(json);
          }).toList();
          isLoading = false;
          return orgModelList;
        } else {
          isLoading = false;
          throw Exception('Failed to load internet');
        }
      }

      @override
      void initState() {
        this.fetchOrganizationData();
        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text("Dashboard"),
        ),

        body: Container(

          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: [Color(0xFF076A72), Color(0xFF64B672)])),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Color(0xFF34A086),
                height: 1,
              ),

              isLoading ? loadProgressIndicator() : Expanded(
                child: Padding(

                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
                  child: ListView(children: <Widget>[])

                    ---my code goes here---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must call setState(() => isLoading = false;) so Flutter can update the state of the view, and in doing so It will hide your CircularProgressIndicator.

Answer (score 1):

```
Exception('Failed to load internet'); <-
```

not a good idea since you'r calling the fetchOrganizationData() without a try catch block

It would be better to try something like :

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool isFailure = false;
  List<OrganizationModel> orgModelList; // this was missing

//since your not using the return value ( it's saved in the state directly ) you could not set the return type
  fetchOrganizationData() async {
    isLoading = true;
    isFailure = false;

    var response = await http.get(organizationAPI);          
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      orgModelList = items.map<OrganizationModel>((json) {
        return OrganizationModel.fromJson(json);
      }).toList();
      isFailure = false;
      // the return is not required 
    } else {
      isFailure = true;
    }
    isLoading = false;
    setState((){}); // by calling this after the whole state been set, you reduce some code lines
//setState is required to tell flutter to rebuild this widget


  }
```

This way you have a isFailure flag saying if something went wrong while fetching.